# Spark YARN cluster remains underutilized

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark

Using Microsoft Azure, I have a cluster with 2 master nodes and 50 worker nodes. All nodes have 8 cores and 64 GB of RAM.

I am running a spark-submit job using pyspark. The most relevant part of my Python code is where I create a Python list `arg_list` of tuples of length 72. (Each tuple has about 6 elements and no two tuples are the same.) I then create an RDD with 72 partitions like so,

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize(arg_list, len(arg_list))
```

My goal is to process all 72 partitions at the same time. Processing a partition involves the following:

1. Read two files from Blob (HDFS) storage based on the values of the tuple elements received.
2. Run a Python package called `gensim` to perform an NLP task using the content of the two files read.

To do this, I submit my spark-submit job as follows,

```
spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 100 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 19G /path/to/my/file.py
```

The thinking is as follows. Use each worker node for 2 executors. Each executor gets 3 cores, so each node has 8-2*3=2 cores remaining for node managers and any other overhead tasks. Since I can get 2 executors per node and I have 50 nodes, I get 100 executors. (I admit that the cluster is a bit larger than needed in this case.)

When I run this code, I can monitor the activity of the worker nodes using Ambari. I had expected 72/2 = 36 worker nodes to be busy (as evidenced by average load) and 50-36=14 nodes to be idle. Instead, I see that only 12 nodes are busy and appear to be running 6 processes each.

It's maybe not a coincidence that 6*12=72, the number of tasks. It's as if Spark/YARN decided to ignore my parameters and cram the processing of my partitions into as few nodes as possible.

I also note that it seems to be taking a long time for any one of the 72 tasks to complete. I say this based on seeing a typical task take 3 hours when run in serial mode and seeing my Spark job run for 6 hours with no output at all.

**Questions**:

1. Why am I using only 12 out of 50 worker nodes?
2. Why is my code running so slow?

I've read guidelines on parameters for spark-submit/Yarn and thought what I wrote made sense. Is there some additional parameter setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Spark will process each partition depending on the total amount of cores available to the job you're running.

Let's say your spark job has 100 executors, each one with 3 cores. This means that you'll be able to process 100 x 3 = 300 partitions concurrently, assuming `spark.task.cpus` is set to 1.

`spark.task.cpus` is the number of cores to allocate for each task and `--executor-cores` specify Number of cores per executor.

worker node with 2 executors, process 2 x 3 = 6 partitions. And default spark.default.parallelism = 12. So 6x12 = 72.

The two configuration properties in Spark to tune the number of partitions at runtime are as follows:

[image]

Increase the default parallelism by

```
--conf spark.default.parallelism=36 --conf spark.default.parallelism=36
```

set `spark.task.cpus=2` and `--executor-cores 4` (in spark submit command). So each node will process only (4/2 =) 2 partitions. In this case 36 nodes will be used in processing data in parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. To be clear, it is not necessary to change any underlying configuration files. I can set these two variables (spark.task.cpus and spark.default.parallelism) in the spark-submit command via —conf spark.default.parallelism=36 spark.task.cpus=2. Is that right?

Comment: To be clearer, you say "increase the default parallelism by
   --conf spark.default.parallelism=36 spark.default.parallelism=36". I assume what you meant is --conf spark.default.parallelism=36 spark.task.cpus=2?

Comment: yes. if you pass --conf spark.task.cpus=2  --executor-cores=4 then your each node will process 2 partitions. There are 72 partitions so there will be 36 nodes. Provide these parameters also for change the default parallelism --conf spark.default.parallelism=36 --conf spark.default.parallelism=36